# Css dynamic apply class style

Tags: html, css, sass

I have used CSS Select all element *** ***.
Now using **node-*** class name dynamically changed for node-1, node-2.

```
.page-node #node-* p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

It's Possible for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a attribute match on the id.

```
.page-node [id^=node-] p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp